# UISearchBar in navigation bar from UIBarButton in iOS7

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem

I would like to have my search bar launched from a `UIBarButton` that I have added to my navigation bar from the storyboard. I have also added the Search Bar and Search Display Controller to the document outline in my view controller from the storyboard.

If I implement the code below in my `viewDidLoad` method the search bar will automatically appear in my navigation bar         `self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;`

However, when I try and implement this in from a button click from my navigation bar nothing happens.
    `(IBAction)serachBarButton:(id)sender 
{
    self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
}`

The IBAction is properly hooked up to the view controller in the storyboard. Any code examples of how to launch the search bar from my navigation button click would be greatly appreciated.